# Optional generic parameter in struct

Tags: ios, swift, generics, struct

```
struct JSONAPIResponse<D: Decodable, M: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: D
    let meta: M?
}
```

I have struct which takes 2 generic types. But 2nd type(M) should be optional. I mean that I want to use this block of code without error:

```
JSONAPIResponse<DatumEntity>
```

But now should use pattern:

```
JSONAPIResponse<DatumEntity, MetaEntity>
```

So question, how to refactor **JSONAPIResponse** struct, after that I can use *JSONAPIResponse* code without error

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your error, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
 Show the error message you get (in full), and on what line of your code.

Comment: I think you are going to need 2 separate types for this. Or skip the M for the type declaration and only use it in a function declaration if possible.

Comment: To use just one struct definition, the language would have to support default generic specification parameters, similar to the way C++ templates can.  I seem to recall some Swift evolution thing about it.  I haven't actually looked at the very latest released Swift features in detail, but as far I know, there isn't a way to do it, at least not with officially released Swift.   As @JoakimDanielson said, you'll probably need to have two types, but you can use a protocol + protocol extension to avoid too much code duplication.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson did that sh*t :D Thanks